# How to I setup nginx.conf for a simple proxy pass redirect?

Tags: nginx, proxy, redirect, ghost-blog

I'm trying to set up what might be the "hello world" of proxy pass redirects.  It entails a default route, and one single conditional route.

I want all of the traffic to my server to proxy some ip 1.2.3.4 unless it matches `/blog` in which case it should proxy 5.5.5.5

I've spent some time guessing and checking with the config, and read a bunch of docs, but the amount of variance is overwhelming, and I can't seem to find an anchor point of even a single fully functional simple example to seed from.  So far, this is what I think should work:

```
http {
  server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
      proxy_pass 1.2.3.4
    }

    location ~ /blog {
      proxy_pass 5.5.5.5
    }
  }
}
```

I've updated the config like so and reloaded without any errors, but when I navigate to the server I just get the default `Welcome to nginx!` landing page.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Your server block is missing the `server_name` directive.

From [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html):

> In this configuration nginx tests only the request’s header field “Host” to determine which server the request should be routed to. **If its value does not match any server name**, or the request does not contain this header field at all, **then nginx will route the request to the default server for this port**.

Highlighting by me.

Your block has no server name, so the request is routed to the default server, which is defined in the default config.

You only need to add `server_name`:

```
http {
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    # the rest of your config
}
}
```

No need to remove everything from the default config.

Answer (score 0):

Ends up this setup is mostly correct.  `listen 80` can be dropped as that's the default value, otherwise it's fine.

My issue was that the default ubuntu installation has some stuff that needs to be specifically disabled.  I found an answer by looking at this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460935/nginx-only-shows-welcome-page

In short, navigate to `etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.  `ls` to see what's in there.  If you see anything that's linked you can use `sudo unlink ./default-or-name-of-item`.

Then there won't be anything in sites enabled to serve... my guess is that `location /` is really, really low on the totem poll or priorities when choosing something to serve.

Comment: all you needed was a `server_name` directive. With a name present your server block would have gotten precedence over the defaults.